# LDAP add olcAttributeTypes

Tags: configuration, attributes, ldap, schema, openldap

I'm trying to create a custom AttributeType with OpenLDAP without success...
I have a very basic/default LDAP configuration using the cn=config method.

My goal is to create a custom attribute type "memberOfGroups" for my generic user accounts. The syntax shall validate at least this kind of regular expression: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+(,[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` in other words `one,or,several,words,separated,by,comma`.
So, first of all, I think I should create a new olcAttributeTypes, then modify the inetorgperson and add this Attribute type. Am I right?

This is my ldif file:

```
# cat -A ~/add_attribute.ldif 
version: 1$
$
dn: cn={4}custom,cn=schema,cn=config$
changetype: modify$
add: olcAttributeTypes$
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.1$
  NAME 'memberOfGroups'$
  DESC 'Appartenance a un groupe.'$
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.44 )$
```

And I'm using the following ldapmodify command:

```
# ldapmodify -xf ~/add_attribute.ldif -D 'cn=admin,dc=ldap,dc=jlo,dc=lab' -W
```

The result is:

```
modifying entry "cn={4}custom,cn=schema,cn=config"
ldap_modify: No such object (32)
    matched DN: cn=schema,cn=config
```

So I tried :

- with ldapadd command, with the same result.
- changing the "changetype" to "add", not working too.

Then I'm asking myself if I'm using the right DN. Indeed, the cn={4}custom file doesn't exist yet in the /etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=schema directory.
Should I create it before or will it be automatically created?

I'm a little confused with the LDAP configuration...
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why? You seem to be really looking for the OpenLDAP 'memberof' overlay, which will automatically maintain this information for you.

Comment: I'm trying to link the ldap server to a specific application which get all attributes but, for an obscure reason, don't get the overlay 'memberof'.
And by now, I want to understand deeper the ldap configuration with ldif files.

Comment: I don't know what 'for an obscure reason don't get the overlay memberof' means, but it is certainly the answer to your problem.

Comment: In fact, I asked the product support about the LDAP configuration, this is what they said me: "We are using a LDAP query that is getting all standard attributes, but not the operational attributes, that's why we can't use the memberof overlay at the moment". They will resolve the issue in a next release.
Sorry for my medium level of english.

Answer (score 1):

I progressed (a little). I created a new file for my custom attributes. This is my ldif:

```
dn: cn={4}custom,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: add
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
cn: custom

dn: cn={4}custom,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAttributeTypes
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.1234.1
  NAME 'memberOfGroups'
  DESC 'Appartenance a un groupe.'
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.44 )
```

But don't see the memberOfGroups attribute in phpldapadmin > schema > attribute types. I don't now if this is a phpldapadmin problem or not.

Then, I think I should associate this attribute to the inetOrgPerson objectclass.